# Is there a way to programmatically (or from the terminal) check whether any app engine indexes are building?

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment, indexing

Our team does a lot of rapid iteration and deployment, and I'm trying to make it safer to deploy (knowing you won't bring down the site). I've implemented regular tests but one thing that's plagued us a few times is the site being deployed with queries based on new indexes that someone else has just deployed (but the indexes haven't finished building, so any page that uses them fails with a NeedIndexError).

I'm looking for a way to implement a check in our deploy script that will respond if any of the indexes are still building before if attempts the deploy.

Does anyone know if you can check this from the terminal or through some API? I've not had any luck finding one, and I'm hoping to not have to go down the route of scraping the App Engine console's indexes page to check for the word "building".

Comment: Shouldn't you use versions, then a new deployment can go up, just not activated as default until such time as the indexes finish.  You still need to monitor things before making the new version default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following snippet will block until all indexes are done building. I use it before running `update`.

(In gist form: https://gist.github.com/jgeewax/5650457)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Need to import and fix the sys path before importing other things.
import remote_api_shell
remote_api_shell.fix_sys_path()

import time

from google.appengine.api import datastore_admin
from google.appengine.ext.remote_api import remote_api_stub
from google.appengine.tools import appengine_rpc


def configure_remote_api():
  def auth_func():
    return ('<YOUR_EMAIL>', '<APP_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD>')

  remote_api_stub.ConfigureRemoteApi(
      '<APP_ID>', '/_ah/remote_api', auth_func,
      servername='<APP_ID>.appspot.com',
      save_cookies=True, secure=False,
      rpc_server_factory=appengine_rpc.HttpRpcServer)
  remote_api_stub.MaybeInvokeAuthentication()


def main():
  print 'Checking indexes...'

  configure_remote_api()

  interval = 10  # seconds.
  building = True

  while building:
    # Start with a fresh run: maybe we're done building?
    building = False

    for index in datastore_admin.GetIndices('s~<APP_ID>'):
      # If any single index is building, we're not done.
      # Sleep for a bit and then this cycle should repeat.
      if not index.has_state() or index.state() != index.READ_WRITE:
        building = True
        print 'Indexes are still building... Waiting %s seconds.' % interval
        time.sleep(interval)
        break

  print 'All indexes are up to date.'


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Answer (score 2):

ok, I remembered something from the dim dark past.  (You haven't said if your using python or java, so here is something to try with python).

google.appengine.api.datastore_admin  has a number of methods related to information about indexes.
Specifically GetIndices call.  I don't have any building indexes at the moment so I can't see exactly what state a building index is in. But have look below and you will get the idea.

Below is from a remote_api_shell session.

```
s~xxxx> from google.appengine.api import datastore_admin
s~xxxx> x=datastore_admin.GetIndices()
s~xxxx> x[0]
<google.appengine.datastore.entity_pb.CompositeIndex instance at 0x926fa2c>

s~xxxx> x[0].has_state()
1
s~xxxx> x[0].state()
2
s~xxxx> x[0].State_Name(x[0].state())
'READ_WRITE'


s~xxxx> print str(x[0])
app_id: "s~xxxx"
id: 1
definition <
  entity_type: "Plant"
  ancestor: false
  Property {
    name: "class"
    direction: 1
  }
  Property {
    name: "family"
    direction: 1
  }
  Property {
    name: "name"
    direction: 1
  }
>
state: 2

s~xxxx>
```

So with a bit of poking around you may well be able to see when an index stops building.  At that point you can use `appcfg` to promote a specific version to default or kick off some tests for the new deployment etc....

Let us know what you see with index state against a building index.

For completeness I actually asked about getting the definition of indexes programatically back in 2009 and Nick Johnson alerted me to this capability.  See groups post [https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-appengine/defined$20indexes/google-appengine/nCzSLJkoZuQ/X4GQ0GMBI0gJ](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-appengine/defined%2420indexes/google-appengine/nCzSLJkoZuQ/X4GQ0GMBI0gJ)

Comment: Ah thanks! I'll try this over the weekend and update whether it worked for me.
(and yes, I'm using Python).